# How to discover the paths of two nodes in an endpoint or different endpoints

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data

How to discover the paths of two nodes in an endpoint, preferably the paths of different endpoints. Can sparql be implemented ,  or is there any other way to do it

Comment: can you give an example please? I mean, getting "paths" between two nodes via SPARQL was already asked and answered on StackOverflow (did you try the search functon here), but maybe you're asking for different things?

Comment: what clearly won't work (or scale) is to find paths between nodes located in 2 different endpoints. Given a node `n1` located at endpoint `e1` and node `n2` located at `e2`  , you would have to start with path length 1 on `e1` and for each intermediate node `n_i` check in `e2` for paths to `n2` - depending on the distance that seems to be infeasible in practice. But who knows, you can give it a try